# How to proceed to the further processor if the Listfile should contain the three specific file in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

This is my folder structure:

**
abcd_xxx.txt

xxx_completed.txt

phone_detail[0-9]+.txt**

.

[image]

I have ListFile Processor to picks all the file on this folder. But i should to move on if all the above file is present Otherwise it'll be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t think that the ListFiles Processor will necessarily do way you want without some additional work. However, What you could do is use the [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/additionalDetails.html) processor or similar scripting processor to have a script list the files as output if the required file exists.